# How to handle the Return to Safari button click from ios app

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app that is launched from a url in safari.  On the top of the app is a < safari button that returns to the calling safari tab.  I would like to my app to handle the event and close resources that I'm using when the < safari button is tapped.

I've searched with no success.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know that a user tapped the "return to previous app" link in the status bar.

All your app can detect is that it has entered the background. But of course that could happen for many other reasons.